# Deriving join density

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be uniform on the interval $[0,1]$

And let $U=\min(X,Y)$ and $V=\max(X,Y)$

Derive the joint density of $(U,V)$.

Since the joint pdf is non zero only when $ u\le t$

Here's what I have done
$$\begin{align}P(U\le u,T\le t)&=1-P(X\gt t \ \cap Y>t) - P(u\lt X \lt t\         \cap u\lt Y\lt t) \\&=1-(1-t)^2-(t-u)^2\end{align}$$

But how do I get the joint density

Comment: This was asked multiple times on the site. Note that $$P(u<U,V<v)=(v-u)^2$$ for every $0<u<v<1$ hence the PDF is the second derivative $$f_{U,V}(u,v)=2\,\mathbf 1_{0<u<v<1}$$

Comment: what is the 1 in bold for

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: Alternatively, you can derive the joint pdf directly. This is a problem related to [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Probability_distributions_of_order_statistics).

Comment: @Flowsnake More directly than in my comment? How? Saying "it is known" in one way or another does not count...